# what's the meaning of list[index, :] in Python

Tags: python, list

What's the difference between list[index, :] and list[index:]??

```
for line in arraylines:
   line  = line.strip()
   listFromLine = line.split('\t')
   returnMat[index, :] = listFromLine[0:3]
```

At the beginning, returnMat is a zero matrix.

Comment: The former is [specific to `numpy` arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) which can be multidimensional

Comment: Do you mean `line.strip()`?

Comment: `list[index, :]` is not valid syntax if `list` is a python list; you should explain what data structures you are using.

Comment: @Akavall just to be pedantic, the *syntax* is fine, actually, but it will throw a `TypeError` because you passed a `tuple`, and the `list.__getitem__` method only accepts `int` and `slice` objects...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`returnMat[index, :]` is an example of numpy's [array slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) syntax. It would retrieve rows (different rows correspond to the first index) of the matrix (`:` means "get all of this index"). Example:

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.zeros((3, 5))

print(mat)  # 3 rows and 5 columns of zeros
mat[1, :] = 1
print(mat)  # all of second row is now ones
```

---

To go a bit further, it looks like you're constructing a matrix row-by-row from a file in your code snippet, which means you probably need to be doing something with `index` as well. I would suggest looking into [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Answer (score -1):

```
list[index,:]: starts from index number till the end
list[index:]: it has ranged between numbers which are the output.
```

Comment: `list[index,:]` is not valid Python syntax if `list` is a standard Python list (it raises a `TypeError` because you're trying to index with a tuple). The `list` needs to be a numpy array (or something else which has a special `__getitem__` that allows tuples on slice objects.

Comment: but these are the standard convention followed in python.

Comment: This is a spectacularly wrong answer in that it completely fails to explain what multiple slices or indices separated by commas mean in numpy.